# Criteria collection-field access

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria-api

i have problem with access to Collection-field in my class with Criteria.

I have 2 entity:
First, that mapped to other entity

```
@Table(name = "MAIN_ENTITY")
public class MainEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = ID_MAIN, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mappedField")
    private Set<SecondEntity> secondEntities = new HashSet<>(0); 

    ...................
}
```

And second, that loaded to first entity.

```
@Table(name = "SECOND_ENTITY")
public class SecondEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = ID_SECOND, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal id;

    @Column(name = SOME_FLAG, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal someFlag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = MAIN_ENTITY_FK, nullable = false)
    private MainEntity mainEntity;

    ...................
}
```

I want to get count of secondEntities in MainEntity records, where field someFlag = 0

For this i have class that extends MainEntity and have field count

```
public class MainEntityDto extends MainEntity {
    private MainEntity entity;
    private Integer count;
    ...................
}
```

then i'm trying to build query, i write this:

```
Path secondEntitiesPath = root.<Set>get("secondEntities");
cq.select(cb.construct(MainEntityDto.class, root, cb.size(secondEntitiesPath)));
```

It's working good if i want to get count of all second entities, for example if i have 100 entities, i will get count = 100, and I can work with this entity later in my code.
BUT I want to get count of entities where field Flag = 0. 
I was trying to write something like

```
cq.select(cb.construct(MainEntityDto.class, root, 
    cb.size(secondEntitiesPath))).where(cb.equal(
    secondEntitiesPath.<BigDecimal>get("Flag"), BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

but this just create another join, and have no effect on count, and it still returns 100.
I just can't get access to the elements of the Set in my queries. I was trying it in hundred different ways, but i always have something like

```
SELECT COUNT(t.id)
FROM SECOND_ENTITY se
WHERE (se.MAIN_ENTITY_FK = mainEntity.ID)
```

and after it i have another join that have conditional that i wrote.

Sorry guys, if it looks like a mess, and you can't understand anything. I got stuck on it for 3 days, and maybe can't think clearly. I will update this topic if someone asks for more code or etc. I will very appreciate all comments, thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the sub query.  In JPQL it would look something like:
 "SELECT new MainEntityDto(entity, (select count(secondEntities) from SecondEntity secondEntities where secondEntities.mainEntity = entity and secondEntities.flag=0)) from MainEntity entity"

Using criteria API would look something like:

```
Subquery sq = cb.subquery(SecondEntity.class);
Root<SecondEntity> second= sq.from(SecondEntity.class);
sq.select(cb.count(second));
sq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(second.get("mainEntity"), root), cb.equal(second.get("flag"), 0));

cq.select(cb.construct(CodeSubjectDto.class, root, sq));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some advice, and now count with some conditional criteria query should be look like

```
final Join<MainEntity, SecondEntity> secondEntityJoin =
    root.join(secondEntities, JoinType.LEFT);
secondEntityJoin.on(cb.equal(secondEntityJoin.<BigDecimal>get("someFlag"), BigDecimal.ZERO))); 
cq.select(cb.construct(CodeSubjectDto.class, root, cb.count(secondEntityJoin)));
```

But now new problem has appeared in SQL query, because I have to use group by with count. This problem will be solved later and i will post out final decision. To solve this problem, i can use multiselect, or make second query, but it's not appropriate for our high-load application architecture. Also we have found that weight of this query is too high and maybe it will be redesigned

UPD some important info, why i haven't found it at the start:

cb.size returns type int -> In MainEntityDto I have to have constructor with parameters(MainEntity, int)

cb.count returns type long -> In MainEntityDto I have to have constructor with parameters (MainEntity, !!LONG!!)

This's why i couldn't build this at the start. That query returns error, but i didn't understand, that there was problem with constructor.